# How to get a certain date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I am trying to get the current day then getting the day before it, how can I get that date then convert it into a String?

```
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
```

Comment: What was your correct wanted output/result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing:

```
   DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:1))
```

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime nowMinus1Day = now. subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
print(nowMinus1Day.toIso8601String());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var startDate= now.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
print(startDate);
```